# Hadith about The future

Tags: hadith

What is the specific Hadith number of a Hadith from Ahmad which spoke about people traveling long distances in short spans of time?

Comment: I don't know if there is any such hadith. There is a hadith on time passing quickly which is interpreted by some as a hint towards faster travel, see https://islamqa.info/en/answers/34618/.